# how to instantiate a different class by Instrumenting / ASM

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to use ASM in a javaagent [to change the class that is being constructed](https://github.com/fommil/class-monkey/tree/ba6903339cae7ebd002189487483878d68f3cda5) (`sun/misc/URLClassPath`) to another one (`fommil/URLClassPath`) that inherits from it and overrides all the methods. I know that the target class (`java/net/URLClassLoader`), which I am `retransforming`, is the only thing that creates `sun/misc/URLClassPath`s and only in its constructor.

The basic idea is something like this:

```
@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access,
                                 String name,
                                 String desc,
                                 String signature,
                                 String[] exceptions) {
    MethodVisitor visitor = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);

    return new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, visitor) {
        @Override
        public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean itf) {
            if (opcode == Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL && "sun/misc/URLClassPath".equals(owner) && "<init>".equals(name)) {
                super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, "fommil/URLClassPath", name, desc, itf);
            } else {
                super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, itf);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**I can put a `println` in `fommil/URLClassPath`'s constructor and see it being constructed!**

However, none of `fommil.URLClassPath`'s methods are being called. Only the methods on the super class are ever called.

Even if I change the above code so that not only `invokespecial` / `<init>`, but all calls to `URLClassPath` are rewritten so that their `invokevirtual` points to my class, my methods are still never called. I've even tried doing this for all of the inner classes of `URLClassLoader`.

So why are the `invokevirtual`s not finding the override methods, even when they are retransformed? Is what I'm doing - changing the type of the thing being constructed - just fundamentally not possible? If so, can somebody please explain *why*?

I am aware that instrumenting core JDK classes is pretty evil, but frankly I don't really have much of an alternative.

The only thing left to try is to instrument all classes that try to instantiate `URLClassLoader` and have them poke into the internal `ucp` field and replace it with my implementation.

Comment: You are using invokespecial which is for constructors (which is correct) not invokevirtual which is for methods which could be overridden.

Comment: @PeterLawrey read the code again, I'm aware of what you're saying. That's not the problem.

Comment: I didn't say it was which is why I commented.  I suspect the URLCLassLoader is being called before your transformation can kick in.  Something has to load the classes your transformer is using.

Comment: this is a retransform. Note the bit: "I can put a println in fommil/URLClassPath's constructor and see it being constructed!"

Comment: Is it being constructed in all places you need it to be used.  e.g. say your JVM creates a URLClassLoader to load all the basic classes and your transformer.  After some of the code has been changed, will your URLClassLoader change type, or will it continue to be used?

Comment: The URLClassLoader that I'm explicitly testing is constructed AFTER the instrumentation. But you make a good point that there may be URLClassLoaders already in memory by this point.

Comment: While you don't use it, it could still be used.  Have you considered Instrumenting the URLClassLaoder class to do what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109336/discussion-between-fommil-and-peter-lawrey).

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

Consider this simple code

```
import java.util.*;    
class Baz {
    public void baz() {
        List list = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

which produces

```
   0: new           #2                  // class java/util/ArrayList
   3: dup
   4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
   7: astore_1
   8: return
```

compared to

```
import java.util.*;    
class Baz {
    public void baz() {
        List list = new LinkedList();
    }
}
```

which produces

```
   0: new           #2                  // class java/util/LinkedList
   3: dup
   4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/LinkedList."<init>":()V
   7: astore_1
   8: return
```

Note the `new` keyword which has a type in it!

The problem is that if one wishes to change the constructor one must also change the type definition that is returned. i.e. add this

```
        @Override
        public void visitTypeInsn(int opcode, String type) {
            if ("sun/misc/URLClassPath".equals(type))
                super.visitTypeInsn(opcode, "fommil/URLClassPath");
            else
                super.visitTypeInsn(opcode, type);
        }
```